# error ORA-01858 when trying to load Master-Detail Page in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to make a master-detail page in apex. This is the tables which i am working with:

```
CREATE  TABLE Comenzi
( 
     Numar_Comanda NUMBER NOT NULL ,
     Data_Comanda DATE NOT NULL ,
     Id_Client NUMBER NULL ,
     Suma NUMBER NULL ,
     ID_Curier NUMBER NULL      ,
     CONSTRAINT PK_Comenzi PRIMARY KEY (Numar_Comanda,Data_Comanda)
```

and the second table is

```
CREATE  TABLE Produse_Comenzi
( 
     Numar_Comanda NUMBER NOT NULL ,
     Data_Comanda DATE NOT NULL ,
     Pozitie NUMBER NOT NULL ,
     ID_Produs NUMBER NULL ,
     Cantitate NUMBER NULL      ,
     CONSTRAINT PK_Produse_Comenzi PRIMARY KEY
```

Also, this is the FK i am using

```
ALTER TABLE Produse_Comenzi ADD
(
     CONSTRAINT FK_Comenzi_Pozitii FOREIGN KEY
     ( Numar_Comanda , Data_Comanda )
     REFERENCES Comenzi
     ( Numar_Comanda , Data_Comanda )
     NOT DEFERRABLE Initially IMMEDIATE
)
```

These pieces of code are from the generated script but i guess it is easier to look at the tables.
In Apex i set the Comenzi table as master. All fields are set on Number field except Data which is Date. I don't understand where does this error come from. Any suggestion?

```
Ajax call returned server error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected for ajax_dispatch_request.
```

Comment: Error comes from the **DATE** datatype column. It seems that value entered into it can't be properly recognized by Oracle. Check its **format mask**.